# How to delete every 2nd column in a dataset from second column, tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe like this

```
date    a b c d e f
1.1.01  1 2 3 4 5 6
```

And I want to remove every second column excluding the date column so it'll end up like this

```
date    a  c  e 
1.1.01  1  3  5
```

I have tried this

```
col_index <- seq(1:ncol(df)) 
data <- df%>% 
select(col_index[col_index %% 2 != 0]
```

But this didn't quite work. Does anyone have some suggestions on how I can do this?
My actual df is quite long which is why I need to code this rather than do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't generating your desired sequence of column indices. You should do something like:

```r
data <- df %>% 
   select(date, seq(2, ncol(.), 2))
```

Here is a reproducible example.

```r
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)

mtcars %>% 
  select(mpg, seq(2, ncol(.), 2)) %>% 
  View("mod_mtcars")
```

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Jason130497 You're welcome. Please consider accepting any of the provided answers.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% 
 select(names(iris[as.logical(c(rep(1, 3), (4:ncol(iris) %% 2)))]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R way using `subset`+ `seq`

```
subset(df1,
  select = -seq(3, ncol(df1), by = 2)
)
```

or a simpler one

```
df1[, -seq(3, ncol(df1), by = 2)]
```

giving

```
    date a c e
1 1.1.01 1 3 5
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(date = "1.1.01", a = 1L, b = 2L, c = 3L, d = 4L, 
    e = 5L, f = 6L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-1L))
```